# Cloudoundry: gwt app,Memory usage steadily increases as per vmc but not in memory profiler

Tags: memory, tomcat7, cloud-foundry, probe

I deployed a gwt app(tomcat7) (file upload and displaying contents in table) .
I used probe to checkout memory usage and the issue is,as per vmc i.e cloudfoundry console,memory never goes down(abnormal) but probe displays something else altogether(normal).
[image]
My initial instinct was that maybe its memory leak in app but probe and vmc stats suggest some other issue.

Comment: Since you are using Tomcat 7, I assume you are deploying the Tomcat binaries bundled with your app as a stand-alone application. Is that correct? If so, is the probe.war file also deployed with the same Tomcat+app bundle?

Comment: @ScottFrederick yeah.whatever you said is absolutely right :)

Answer (score 3):

Reported memory usage is actually the whole unix process RAM usage (this way this is consisten with ruby and node.js deployments). So this takes into account your whole heap + permgen + even some JVM overhead, so this may explain the difference.

Comment: ,the difference maybe explainable that way but not the thing is probe stats /usage varies with time.going little up during load and then comes down afterwards.but vmc stats doesn't come down.steady or increase not decreasing